# Ionic - Cross-Origin Request Blocked Issue

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, cors, ionic-framework

I have setup the Ionic development environment using Yeoman generator (https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic). Everything is works well.

The problem is on Sever side request, I am getting the Cross-Origin Request Blocked error.

I add below link in .htaccess file and AngularJS app.js, still getting same error

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

AngularJS Provider

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Error Message I am getting is

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
http://192.168.1.18/tracker/user/login. 
This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Screen of Request & Response Header

[image: Screen of Request & Response Header]

Please guide me any configuration need to be changed for enabling CORS. Our server side framework is Zend 1.x

Comment: Hope, add this too in your htaccess file Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT" ...I believe, this htaccess file is located inside "245webserver" folder...try and let me know

Comment: Try to set your .htaccess header to: 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the .htaccess files as below and its worked out, Google Chrome is not accepting the '*', so I specified the exact URL

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8100"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Answer (score 10):

The cross origin is forced by your browser, running the application from any distributed phone should not be blocked with your current settings.

To allow communication between your "served to browser" app to your server use a browser plugin

[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) do the work

Comment: Now I am getting the below error "A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true."

Comment: Remove the "withCredentials" I assume you don't need it @Muthu

Comment: any possibility is there in the plugin to add my localhost name instead of '*'

Comment: Yes you can config the plugin

Comment: @BenDiamant I have the same problem with Firefox, Ionic and Symfony 2 running on the Symfony server (localhost:8000, were I can't config .htaccess settings). And I proxy the Ionic app to localhost:8080. I still get "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". I really don't get why the browser blocks a normal API call. Were is the difference between browser and html5 app? Is explained in detail somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have experience using Zend with Ionic, I did experience this issue when interfacing with an IIS hosted REST API via Ionic.

For me, I had to add "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" server side in addition to what you already have.

After adding the 'allow methods' header, I was able to fully utilize my API.

If this doesn't get it for you, report back and I will dig a bit deeper in my project to see if I've forgotten a client side change that were also required.